# What are appropriate situations where you use 何卒 to end a formal correspondence?

Tags: usage, honorifics, formality

I've seen some emails ending with 何卒宜しくお願い致します but I was wondering if it just raises the respect/politeness of a letter or does it have specific situations where it should/shouldn't be use?

Like when you're expecting a response, I usually end with ご回答の程、宜しくお願いします。 But I'm really not that clear with 何卒 usage.

Comment: A quick internet search brought up this page, which explains it clearly: http://whatimi.blog135.fc2.com/blog-entry-91.html
The author says it's basically about adding stress to the お願い.

Comment: In addition to @chigusa's comment, I'll add that I've often seen this used as a more formal synonym for 是非, such as in ご質問等がございましたら [是非・何卒] ご連絡ください。

Answer (score 5):

As something of a fossilized and archaic term, 何卒{なにとぞ} comes across as more formal and stiff.  This would not be used in everyday talk.  Possible use cases in the closing of formal correspondence might be:

- ご質問{しつもん}等{とう}がございましたら **何卒** ご連絡{れんらく}ください。
- **何卒** 宜{よろ}しくお願{ねが}い致{いた}します。
- **何卒** どうぞ宜{よろ}しくお願{ねが}い致{いた}します。
  Some folks consider this last one to be redundant or incorrect with both 何卒 and どうぞ, as these have basically the same meaning, but I do find [numerous examples of use](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E4%BD%95%E5%8D%92%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%9E%E5%AE%9C%E3%81%97%E3%81%8F%E3%81%8A%E9%A1%98%E3%81%84%E8%87%B4%E3%81%97%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99%22) by what appear to be native speakers, so take that for what you will.

Breaking this term down, Shogakukan explains that this is 何{なに} "what" + と (particle) + ぞ (particle), with the 卒 character serving as ateji.  The ぞ isn't used much and might be less well-known.  In this context, it basically serves as an intensifier, a bit like も after question words.  The resulting meaning of the phrase is a bit like English "*whatever the case may be*", or "*no matter what*".  Synonyms listed in the dictionary entry are どうぞして, なんとかして, and どうか.  (Incidentally, the ぞ in なにとぞ is the same ぞ in どうぞ.)

Comment: For what it's worth, the [*Balanced Corpus of Contemporary Written Japanese (BCCWJ)*](http://www.kotonoha.gr.jp/shonagon/) has 4147 results for どうぞ, 72 results for 何卒, and 0 results for 何卒どうぞ.

Comment: Interestingly, there is apparently one example of **どうぞ** 今後とも **何卒** 宜しくお願い申し上げます (hit number 26 when searching for 何卒), suggesting that these words might appear together in different kinds of combinations.

Answer (score 0):

In this case,the 何卒 means "please". It is a bit formal way to tell something to someone.